# How can I put Dictionary to Properties.Resources

Tags: c#, wpf

I write an application in C# WPF.
There is a variable of type Dictionary and I nead to save it after closing of application.
I don't want to save it in *.txt or database. Can I save it in Properties.Resources? How can I do it if possible? Do I nead to use ResourceManager?

Comment: Why not in `.json` file?

Comment: What does the dictionary look like, as initialized from code? What about ser'ing it to json and putting it in a string resource? (Or putting the entries in a stringcollection, and  LINQ ToDictionary'ing them one time to init a static dictionary?

Comment: It sounds like x-y problem. The answer depends on why you want to avoid saving in *.txt or database.

Comment: @Prased I didn't look towards a .json because I don't understand it yet.

Comment: @Caius  The dictionary looks like <code>Dictionary<int,string> dict = new Dictionary<int,string>() </code>

Comment: @emoacht I write offline and light application for learning new words. If use *.txt no the app needed. Using the database increases the size of the program locally or requires a network connection.

Comment: Resources aren't editable. it sounds like you want something that is?

Answer (score 0):

Resources cannot be written to. You'll have to use an external file or a database. JSON is by far the fastest and easiest to get working.

You can use `System.Text.Json` for this.

It is built-in on .NET Core 3.0 and newer.

It is available as a nugget package for these frameworks:

- .NET Standard 2.0 and later versions
- .NET Framework 4.7.2 and later versions
- .NET Core 2.0, 2.1, and 2.2

###### Writing to file:

```
Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    { 1, "One" },
    { 2, "Two" },
    { 3, "Three" }
};    

string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(dictionary);
File.WriteAllText("<YOUR FILE PATH HERE>", jsonString);
```

###### Reading from file:

```
string jsonString = File.ReadAllText("<YOUR FILE PATH HERE>");
Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<int, string>>(jsonString);
```

Obviously, you'll want to do null checking when deserializing, since `Deserialize()` can return null.

For more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to